# Como seleccionar una fila de un data table y que me mande a otra pagina?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable

tengo la siguiente tabla, lo que quiero hacer es que al seleccionar una fila, me mande a otra pagina para poder mostrar datos de acuerdo a la persona que seleccione en la tabla,

```html
<h:form>
  <p:dataTable var="consultaPersona" style="max-width:3000px;max-height:770px;" value="#{ConsultaPersonasUnidadFisicaComponent.listNivelesPersona}" emptyMessage="No se encontraron registros." selectionMode="single" selection="#{ConsultaPersonasUnidadFisicaComponent.nivelesPersona}"
    rowKey="#{consultaPersona.persona.cveIdPersona}">

    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{ConsultaPersonasUnidadFisicaComponent.mostrarPantallaHorario}" />

    <p:column headerText="No.Empleado">
      <h:outputText value="#{consultaPersona.persona.noEmpleado}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="RFC">
      <h:outputText value="#{consultaPersona.persona.rfc}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Nombre">
      <h:outputText value="#{consultaPersona.persona.nombre}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Ubicacion">
      <h:outputText value="#{consultaPersona.unidadAdministrativa.cveIdUnidadAdmin}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Entrada">
      <h:outputText />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Salida">
      <h:outputText />
    </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

ya me selecciona las filas, y le agregue un ajax rowselect, que manda a llamar el siguiente metodo, pero no me hace nada

```
public String mostrarPantallaHorario(SelectEvent event) {
    return RUTA2;
}
```

como puedo hacerle para que al seleccionar la fila me mande a otra pagina?

Answer (score 3):

Prueba haciendo un redirect de forma programatica:

```
public void mostrarPantallaHorario(SelectEvent event) {
    try {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(RUTA2);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //log error?
    }
}
```

Comment: me funciono, gracias

Answer (score -1):

Te iba a decir de añadir el evento onclick a la etiqueta pero he encontrado esta página en la que puedes ver también mas opciones.
https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html